# Proving a sequence does not converge in $[0,2]$ with floor metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have the following question:

Let $(X,d)$ be the metric space such that, $X=[0,2]$, and the metric is defined with:

$d(x,y) = \left| (x + \lfloor x \rfloor ) - ( y + \lfloor y \rfloor ) \right|$

I need to show that the sequence $a_n = 1- \frac{1}{n} $ does not converge. I tried showing it is not a Cauchy sequence, and after performing the initial calculations I arrived at the equation:

$d(a_m,a_n) = \left| \frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{n} \right| $.

I can't find a way to find a value $\varepsilon_0 > 0$ as a lower bound, which would work for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, thus showing the difference between any given pair of values, no matter how far down the sequence can be bounded from below by an absolutely positive number.

Thank you for any hints, or directions!

Answer (score 0):

In fact, $(\forall m,n\in\Bbb N):d(a_m,a_n)=\left|\frac1m-\frac1n\right|$, and therefore $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ *is* a Cauchy sequence.

However, it is indeed true that $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ diverges. Take $l\in\Bbb R$. If $l\geqslant1$, then\begin{align}d(l,a_n)&=\left|l+\lfloor l\rfloor-\left(1-\frac1n\right)\right|\\&=l+\lfloor l\rfloor-\left(1-\frac1n\right)\\&\geqslant l+1-1+\frac1n\\&=l+\frac1n\\&\geqslant1.\end{align}And, if $l\in[0,1)$, then\begin{align}d(l,a_n)&=\left|l+\lfloor l\rfloor-\left(1-\frac1n\right)\right|\\&=\left|l-1+\frac1n\right|\\&>\frac{1-l}2\end{align}when $n$ is such that $\frac1n<\frac{1-l}2$.

Finally, if $l<0$, then $l+\lfloor l\rfloor<-1$, and therefore$$d(l,a_n)=\left|l+\lfloor l\rfloor-\left(1-\frac1n\right)\right|>1-\frac1n\geqslant\frac12$$when $n>1$.

Comment: Thank you for the very elaborated explanation!
I still have a few questions:
1. What made you think in that direction? The one of dividing into cases of L?
2. In the second part, for $\ell \in [0,1)$, wouldn't it be true to say: $\left| l - 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right| > \left| l-1 \right| = 1 - l $? which is by itself some properly positive real number?
3. I don't understand the final case, specifically the first inequality (right after the absolute value).
Thank you again!

Comment: 1. I saw how do it when $l\geqslant1$ and then I started to think how I could do it otherwise. 2. No. If, say, $l=\frac12$ and $n=2$, then $\left|l-1+\frac1n\right|=0$, whereas $|l-1|=\frac12$. 3. Since $l+\lfloor l\rfloor<-1$ and $1-\frac1n>0$,$$\left|l+\lfloor l\rfloor-\left(1-\frac1n\right)\right|$$is the (usual) distance between a negative number ($l+\lfloor l\rfloor$) and a positive number ($1-1/n$), which is greater than the distance from $0$ to that positive number, which, in turn, is that positive number.